# Prove that: $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le m$.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I have a problem:

Suppose $f \in \mathcal{H}(U,F)=\left \{ f: U \to F,~ \text{f is holomorphic mapping} \right \}$.

Where $E,F$ are two complex Banach spaces, $U$ is an open set in $E$.

We assume $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}_0=\{0,1, \ldots\}$ and $c>0$ such that 
$$\left \|f(x)  \right \| \le c (\left \| x \right \|^m+1),~ \forall x \in E$$.

Prove that: $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le m$.

Ps: I need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Lol of course you need our help, if you didn't you wouldn't post here! I believe the 'homological-algebra' tag is completely unappropriate, I'll remove it. Have you tried something? We could try either giving you a hint if you're stuck or work on what you've done. Do you assume your spaces finite-dimensional? Because then you need to make precise what you mean by 'polynomial'.

Comment: Hihi! You're funny! I'm really in trouble, because I'm learning. I hope that you can give me a full answer, which I will learn a lot. Thanks Patrick Da Silva!

Comment: Okay, well I'm willing to help. :) Can you at least answer the questions in my comment? Then I'll see what I can do for you.

Comment: Yes, thanks Patrick Da Silva. I'm very happy :) I have tried, but i still no solution... :( . I'll ans your questions: Yes, my spaces ($E,F$)-finite dimensional. Why $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le m$? I'm learning, so you can post full solution,(you write details), because I'm not good at mathematics. Thanks.

Comment: I have thinked of Cauchy's integral:
$$f(a+\lambda t)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|\zeta|=r}\frac{f(a+\zeta t)}{\zeta - \lambda}d\zeta$$
 and Cauchy's inequality
$$\left \| P^mf(a)(t) \right \| \le r^{-m}\sup_{|\zeta|=r} \left \| f(a+\zeta t) \right \|$$. But i still no solution...I look forward to your help. Thanks.

Comment: What is mean is this : when $E = F = \mathbb C$, then it makes sense to say that $f$ is a polynomial. When $f : \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^m$, what does it mean?

Comment: $f : \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^m$; $x=(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto f(x)=x'=(x'_{1}, \ldots, x'_{m})$.              In my text book: " $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le m$ if $f=f_0+\ldots+f_m, \forall p_k \in \mathcal{P}_a(^kE,F), k=0,\ldots,m$ ". So, I still no solution...I don't understand where we use $\left \|f(x)  \right \| \le c \left \| x \right \|^m,~ ~ \forall x \in E$ .I look forward to your help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought using Cauchy's inequality and get rid of $\| f(a+\zeta t) \| \le c \|a + \zeta t\|^m$ like this? By the way, you can't work with that open set $U$, you need 'all the space' because it's when you let $r \to \infty$ that you will obtain $\|P^m f(a)(t)\| \le c \left( \frac{\|a + \zeta t\|}r \right)^m \underset{r \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$. (Note that the inequality is true for every $r$, which means $P^m f(a)(t) = 0$.) Does that help?

Comment: I must admit your notations confuse me, so sorry if I sound a little off ; but the technique of using Cauchy's inequality and letting $r \to \infty$ is known, I think that's what the exercise wants you to do. Just make sure everything works out.

Comment: In my text book doesn't write $\| f(a+\zeta t) \| \le c \|a + \zeta t\|^m$, Can you explain more detail? And you still haven't answered my questions..:(

Comment: My teacher suggested that using Cauchy's ineq, but I haven't done how to do it. Please, help me (explain more detail). Thanks.

Comment: That inequality is the one you assume in the exercise!

Comment: My text book writes as :" Suppose $U=B(a,r) \subset E$ and assume $f \in \mathcal{H}(U,F)$. For $||f(x)|| \le c$, $\forall x \in B(a,r)$ and $\exists m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $P^jf(a)=0$, with $j<m$ then $||f(x)|| \le c (||x-a||/r)^m$, with $x \in B(a,r)$ ".     I have difficulty when I used Cauchy's ineq, please! I'm a student, and i'm not good at maths.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9248/discussion-between-patrick-da-silva-and-kimtahe6)

Answer (score 1):

I thought I had made a few mistakes here.

We don't need step 1, we only need to show step 2 in proof. Which means:

Since $||a_n||=||\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{| \zeta|=r} \dfrac{f(a+\zeta  t) \mathrm{d} \zeta}{\zeta^{n+1}} ||$

$\le \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{|\zeta|=r} \dfrac{||f(a+ \zeta t)|| \cdot | \mathrm{d}\zeta |}{| \zeta |^{n+1}}$

$=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi} (2 \pi r)\dfrac{C(|\zeta|^{m}+1)}{|\zeta|^{n+1}}$

$=\dfrac{C(r^{m+1}+r)}{r^{n+1}}$, $|\zeta|=r$, $\forall n>m, \mathrm{C}>0$.

$=\dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r^{n-m}}+\dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r^{n}}$

Let $r \to +\infty$ that I will obtain $||a_n||=\|P^m f(a)(t)\|\le \left(\dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r^{n-m}}+\dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r^{n}} \right)  \underset{r \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

Therefore, $a_n=0,~~~ \forall n>m$.

Do you think so? Patrick. :)

Comment: Yes, you're right! We can't work with that open set $U$, we need 'all the space', We replace $U$ by $E$, it means $\mathcal{H}(E,F)$.

Comment: Yes, in the case where $E = F = \mathbb C$, you have done the right proof. I don't exactly know how to formulate things in the general case.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But I think:  $||a_n||\le \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{|\zeta|=r} \dfrac{||f(a+ \zeta t)|| \cdot | \mathrm{d}\zeta |}{| \zeta |^{n+1}} \le \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} (2 \pi r)\dfrac{C(||a+ \zeta t||^{m}+1)}{|\zeta|^{n+1}}$. Whether we can choose $\boxed{a = 0}$ so $||a_n||\le \dfrac{c(r^m||t||^m+1)}{r^n} \underset{r \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0, \forall n>m $. I look forward to your reply. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! **Patrick**.

With Patrick's hints, I will rewrite as follows:

We show that $a_n=0$, for $n>m$.

Firstly, we show that: $||f(x)|| \le \mathrm{C}||x||^m$.

$||x||^m+1 \le 2||x\||^m,~~ \forall ||x|| \ge 1$

Hence, $\implies ||f(x)|| \le 2C||x||^m=\mathrm{C}||x||^m$

Step 2: We'll have to get the bound $\||f(x)\|| \le \dfrac{ \mathrm{C}}{r^{n-m}}$,$ \forall n>m$.

Since $||a_n||=||\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{| \zeta|=r} \dfrac{f(a+\zeta  t) \mathrm{d} \zeta}{\zeta^{n+1}} ||$

$\le \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{|\zeta|=r} \dfrac{||f(a+ \zeta t)|| \cdot | \mathrm{d}\zeta |}{| \zeta |^{n+1}}$

$=\dfrac{1}{2 \pi} (2 \pi)\dfrac{C(|\zeta|^{m+1}+1)}{|\zeta|^{n+1}}$

$=\dfrac{C(|\zeta|^{m+1}+1)}{|\zeta|^{n+1}}$

$=\dfrac{C(|r|^{m+1}+1)}{r^{n+1}}$

$\le \dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r^{n-m}}$

Let $r \to +\infty$ that I will obtain $||a_n||=\|P^m f(a)(t)\|\le \dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r^{n-m}}  \underset{r \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$.

Therefore, $a_n=0$, with $n>m$.

It means $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\le m$. :P

*. I'm trying in case:

If $||x|| \le 1$ then $||f(x)|| \le 2c=\mathrm{C}$. It means $m=0$

$\implies||a_n|| \le \dfrac{\mathrm{C}}{r}$.

Is it right? Patrick.

Can you help me? Thanks.   [Prove that: $\sup_{z \in \overline{D}} |f(z)|=\sup_{z \in \Gamma} |f(z)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420046/prove-that-sup-z-in-overlined-fz-sup-z-in-gamma-fz/420067?noredirect=1#comment898459_420067)

Comment: Can we talk? You never added me on facebook and the chatting on MSE is horrible

Comment: I'm sorry, Patrick. :(