# Prove that: $f$ is not a constant function on the open unit disc $\Delta (0,1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I have come across the following questions from my text book! However, I'm not sure how to go about answering... Any help (or hint) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Suppose $F=\mathbb{C}^2$ with norm $\sup$.
For $f: \mathbb{C} \to F$, the function $f$ be defined by $f(z)=(1,z)$, $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.

Prove that:

a. $f  \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C},F)$

b. $\left \|f  \right \|$ is constant on the open unit disc $\Delta (0,1)$

c. $f$ is not a constant function on the open unit disc $\Delta (0,1)$

d. $\left \|f  \right \|$ is not a constant on $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You have $||f(z)||= \max (1,|z|)$. So if $z \in \Delta(0,1)$, $|z| <1$ hence $||f(z)||=1$; if $z \notin \Delta(0,1)$, $|z| \geq 1$ hence $||f(z)||=|z|$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand :( Can you say more details? b. $||f||$ is constant on the open unit disc $\Delta(0,1)$ and d. on $\mathbb{C}$, .I can not distinguish the difference between them. Seirios! Thanks.

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Seirios. Now, I understand b. and d. You explained to me that is very easy to understand. Can you add your hint for c. I look forward to your help. Seirios!

Comment: You just have to find $z_1,z_2 \in \Delta(0,1)$ such that $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$, so it seems pretty easy.

Comment: Aargh I've answered the "same", using mobile internet in mountain doesn't allow me to refresh the page and see updates. Sorry and +1 to this complete answer!

Comment: Yeah!Seirios. c. If $f$ is a constant function on the open unit disc $\Delta(0,1)$ then $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$, $\forall z_1,z_2 \in \Delta(0,1)$. Since your hint I'll find $z_1,z_2 \in \Delta(0,1)$ so $f(z_1)=(1,z_1)=f(z_2)=(1,z_2) $ iff $z_1=z_2$, is it right?

Comment: I think $||f||=\sup(1,|z|)$ not $\max(1,|z|)$.             R u ok? Seirios?

Comment: You are right. For $\sup$ or $\max$, it is the same thing here.

Comment: Yes, Serios. I think of a. as i wrote above! Is it right, can you check it for me, or add your hint? I mean that $f\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C},F)$. Thanks Serios!

Comment: In fact, I do not know the notation $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C},F)$. What is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not say the obvious since my assumption. Which means: $\mathcal{P}(E,F)$ be a vector space of all polynomials (continuous) from $E$ into $F$. ($E=\mathbb{C}$ and $F=\mathbb{C}^2$).

Comment: What is a polynomial from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}^2$? Probably, it means that $f=(f_1,f_2)$ where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are polynomials $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, right? In this case, $1$ and $z$ are clearly polynomials.

Comment: Yes, $1$ and $z$ are polynomials. Hence, we can write "it's obvious"? Seirios. I'm sorry if I asked the question was stupid.

Comment: It depends on what really means $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C}^2)$. Usually, polynomials are functions from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. So if I guessed the correct definition, yes, it is obvious.

Comment: Yes, I think so. In my text book: "**Lemma**: If $P:K^n \to F$ is polynomial in each variable then $P$ is polynomial". I think It's obvious!

Comment: I have a new problem, I thought about it, but I have difficulty...Can you help me, plz http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420046/prove-that-sup-z-in-overlined-fz-sup-z-in-gamma-fz

Comment: Thank you very much, Seirios! Since your explanation I have understood the problem quickly and easily. You are very good.

Answer (score 0):

If you conpute the norm using elements of the open disc, it will always be 1, for the definition of the disc $B_0(1)$ (I use this notation) which contains every element whose norm is less of 1. Then use the definition in the "hint" and you will be ok. D) follows easily for the same reason.

the other points are immediate.

Comment: Can you post your hint for a. Ric Ped! I have thought $(1,z)=(1,0)+(0,z)$, Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much! Seirios and Ric Ped.

With **Seirios**'s hints, I will rewrite as follows:

We consider: $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^2$, $f$ is defined by $f(z)=(1,z)$.

a. $f \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C}^2)$.

it is obvious. Because, $f(z)=(f_1,f_2)=(1,z)$ is a polynomial and continuous, since $f_1=1$ and $f_2=z$ are polynomials and continuous.

b. $∥f∥$ is constant on the open unit disc $\Delta(0,1)$.

We have: $\Delta(0,1)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}:|\lambda|<1\}$.

$||f||=\sup_{z}{|f(z)|}=\sup_{z} \{1,|z|\}$.
Hence, if we consider $f$ on $\Delta(0,1)$ $\implies ||f||=1$.

Therefore, $||f||=1$ on $\Delta(0,1)$.

c. $f$ is not a constant function on the open unit disc $\Delta(0,1)$

If $f$ is a constant function on the open unit disc $\Delta(0,1)$ then $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$, $\forall z_1,z_2 \in \Delta(0,1)$.

I show that there exists $z_1=\dfrac{1}{2} \ne z_2=\dfrac{1}{3} \in \Delta(0,1)$ so $f(z_1) \ne f(z_2)$.

d. $∥f∥$ is not a constant on $\mathbb{C}$.

Since a. $f$ on $\Delta(0,1)$ $\implies ||f||=1$

If $z \notin \Delta(0,1)$, $|z| \ge 1$, hence $||f(z)||=|z|$.
Therefore, $||f||$ is not a constant on $\mathbb{C}$. :p